# Is this normal or some kind of issue with `latexmk` automatic processing incase of bibtex errors?

Tags: bibtex, latexmk

In the `latexmk` automatic processing for bibtex, If `bibtex` throws an error that could be resolved with extra runs, `latexmk` stops its "Further Processing" suggesting to use `-f` forced run. I was expecting that, It could resolve the  missing citation warnings in latex .log file. Instead `latexmk` needs 3 manual runs to get the References printed without `?` in pdf doc

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{patashnik88}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

.bib file contents

```
@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{B}ib{T}e{X}ing.  Documentation for General {B}ib{T}e{X} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}

@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{B}ib{T}e{X}ing.  Documentation for General {B}ib{T}e{X} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}
```

bibtex error (due to presence of duplicate bibtex entries):
 `@misc{patashnik88 : , I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry (There was 1 error message)`

Comment: Why would you expect an error to be resolved with further compilations? You've not given the text of the error, but you have given BibTeX two entries with identical keys. That's going to lead it to barf and it is going to barf at `latexmk` which is going to complain. The solution isn't to force anything but to fix the problem in the `.bib` file.

Comment: @cfr If there were undefined citations which could be resolved with extra runs. This is just an example to illustrate, the real bib file errors would be many to narrow down and make them fully error free... . Some kind of errors could be overidden to get the fast output and made a log of that forced compilation summary with these set of errors in `.fdb_latexmk` . may be its appropriate to document `.blg ` and `.log` summary of errors along with `latexmk` console output in `.fdb_latexmk`.

Comment: With bibtex it is as with tex: If you get real errors you should correct them directly and not try to ignore them. Even more if there are many.

Comment: Undefined citations will give you warnings rather than errors. Errors mean problems which render any output you force unreliable anyway. Having errors in the `.bib` is like having errors in the `.tex`: you just need to correct them.